# Calculate negative rollover which resets at 0

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following problem - when we have a negative row we want to carry it over to next rows untill it reaches 0 or becomes positive. Here is the desired "new value":

[Desired Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkVpa.png)
[image]

Not sure if it's a modified running total or some sort of loop.

Comment: What if `row 4` has a value of `60` ? still `new_value` is `0` or `10` ?

Comment: If row 4 has a value of 60 then the new value will be 10. The idea is that only the negative rows are rolled over to subsequent rows untill the overall result is 0 or positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider below recursive approach.

```sql
-- sample data
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS 
SELECT * EXCEPT(offset) 
  FROM UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) row WITH offset
  JOIN UNNEST([100, -100, 50, 50, 25]) value WITH offset USING (offset);

-- a query starts here
WITH RECURSIVE iterations AS (
  SELECT *, value AS new_value FROM sample_table WHERE row = 1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE
          WHEN i.new_value >= 0 THEN t.value
          WHEN i.new_value < 0 THEN i.new_value + t.value
         END AS new_value
    FROM sample_table t JOIN iterations i ON t.row = i.row + 1
)
SELECT * FROM iterations ORDER BY row;

-- query result
+-----+-------+-----------+
| row | value | new_value |
+-----+-------+-----------+
|   1 |   100 |       100 |
|   2 |  -100 |      -100 |
|   3 |    50 |       -50 |
|   4 |    50 |         0 |
|   5 |    25 |        25 |
+-----+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: I need to test a few scenarios, but I believe this works. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sure, but you should note that a recursive approach is not scalable and has a limitation of 500 iterations.  see here -  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/recursive-ctes#troubleshoot